Counting the number of code words between two specific code words.
I'm grappling with a problem involving counting code words generated by a computer program. Here's the question:

A computer program generated all five-letter code words that can be
formed by using letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G, X, Y, Z (repetition is
allowed). When all these words are sorted according to the
alphabetical order, the following list is obtained: AAAAA, AAAAB,...,
AAAAZ, AAABA, AAABB,..., ZZZZY, ZZZZZ. Find the number of code words
between CZYGB and XEFDA, not including these two code words.

I understand that approaching this problem involves understanding the ordering of these code words and counting the ones that fall between the specified range. However, I'm having trouble figuring out an efficient method to tackle this problem.
Could someone please guide me through the steps to solve this problem? Any insights, hints, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!

What happens if you replace the letters with numbers $0,1,\dots,9$?

Watch for "off by one errors"!  In this case you want to exclude the end points, because of "not including these two code words".  In discrete exercises like this one, you will most likely want to subtract 1.

Hi @BenjaminWang, thank you for your idea! I was able to find the answer through your hint. Feel free to post it as an answer.

@nickalh, thank you too! Without your hint, I might have gotten the wrong answer due to a small mistake.

To expand on my hint in the comments:
There are $N=10$ letters in the set $\{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, X, Y, Z\}$. So we map this set to the base-$N$ digits $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.
This means $CZYGB\to29861$ and $XEFDA\to74530$, so there are $74530-29861-1= 44668$ code words between the two (not counting the endpoints).
